# Compute $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{(a^2+x^2)(b^2+x^2)} $ using fourier transform of $e^{-a|x|}$

Tags: fourier-series, fourier-transform

Compute $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{(a^2+x^2)(b^2+x^2)} $ using fourier transform of $e^{-a|x|}$.

I computed the fourier transform of $e^{-a|x|}$, which is $\frac{a}{\pi (a^2+w^2)}$

I'm not sure how to continue from here, I tried using this formula $f(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{(a^2+x^2)}e^{iwx}dw $. But it didn't work. Any suggestions?

I looked at this post: but I still didn't understand how parseval's theorem is used there. [How do I show $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac 1{(a^2+s^2)(b^2+s^2)} ds=\frac {\pi}{ab(a+b)}$ using the solution to the following Fourier transform?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1225732/how-do-i-show-int-infty-infty-frac-1a2s2b2s2-ds-frac-pi)

This wont work: Parseval's theorem [image]

Comment: You could just use the fact that $$\frac1{(a^2+x^2)(b^2+x^2)} = \frac1{b^2-a^2} \left (\frac1{a^2+x^2}-\frac1{b^2+x^2} \right ) $$

Answer (score 1):

Actually:

$$ \mathcal{F} \left [ e^{- a |x|} \right ] (\omega) = \frac{ 2a}{a^2 + \omega^2} $$

As for the integral, you could use one of Plancherel's formulae:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(t) \overline{g (t)} \ \mathrm dt = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \widehat{f} (\omega) \overline{ \widehat{g} (\omega)} \ \mathrm d \omega $$

In this case:

$$ \begin{aligned}   \int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{\mathrm dx}{ \left ( a^2 + x^2 \right ) \left ( b^2 + x^2 \right )} &= \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\mathrm dx}{ \left ( a^2 + x^2 \right ) \left ( b^2 + x^2 \right )} \\ &=  \frac{\pi}{4ab} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}  e^{- (a + b) |\omega |} \ \mathrm d \omega \\ &=  \frac{\pi}{4ab} \left [ \int_{-\infty}^{0} e^{ (a+b) \omega} \ \mathrm d\omega  + \int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-(a+b) \omega} \ \mathrm d\omega  \right ] \\ &= \frac{\pi}{4ab} \left [ \frac{1}{a + b} + \frac{1}{a+b} \right ] \\ &= \frac{ \pi}{2ab (a+b)}              \end{aligned} $$

Comment: Why $\frac{\pi}{4ab}$? in the second equation. why not $\frac{ab}{\pi ^2}$

Comment: I think you're confused by $\omega$; you could say the Fourier transform is actually the one on the left side, but on the same time it could be the one on the right side. The matter is that $ \mathcal{F} \left [ \widehat {f} (t) \right ] (\omega) = 2 \pi f(-t) $; therefore, the choice of which ones to consider transforms and which ones the functions, when using Plancherel, is quite arbitrary.

Comment: Sorry, I mean $ \mathcal{ F} \left [ \widehat {f} (t) \right ] (\omega) = 2\pi f(-\omega) $.