# Evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{x^4 + 7x^2 + 6} dx$ using Fourier analysis

Tags: fourier-analysis, improper-integrals, fourier-transform

By using Fourier transform methods compute the integral $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{x^4 + 7x^2 + 6} \ dx.$$

I know that I should use the inversion formula and evaluate it in some point, but I can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: If that helps the integral equals $\frac{\pi}{5} (1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}})$ but I calculated it using residues.

Comment: You can also calculate the integral using partial fractions (just as an alternative).

Comment: Note that
$$\frac{1}{x^4+7x^2+6}=\frac{1}{(x^2+1)(x^2+6)},$$
and see [Compute $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{(a^2+x^2)(b^2+x^2)} $ using fourier transform of $e^{-a|x|}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2133283) or [How do I show $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac 1{(a^2+s^2)(b^2+s^2)} ds=\frac {\pi}{ab(a+b)}$ using the solution to the following Fourier transform?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1225732).

Comment: Okay, this was absolutely useful. Thank you.